# Fetch Sum of amount between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

[image]

[This is my table data]

[ what i want is select total of received amount for particular acc_no and that i had done with sum(received_amount) but i want sum(received_amount) for current month also among all details from other my table and this two also.]

I am trying to fetch sum of amount between two days like from start of current month to today's date and total of amount also for every month of particular person.

my table data is like

```css
td {
border: 1px solid #777;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>acc_no</td>
    <td>received_date</td>
    <td>amount_received</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>23-02-2017</td>
    <td>60</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>23-02-2017</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>23-02-2017</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>24-02-2017</td>
    <td>60</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>16-01-2017</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>18-01-2017</td>
    <td>90</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now what i want is total sum of amount_received for acc_no 1 and sum of amount_received for acc_no but for current month only also

i have this query

```
SELECT me.*,SUM(de.amount_received) as total_amount 
                                    FROM members as me 
                                    LEFT JOIN deposit as de on me.id = de.acc_no
                                    WHERE acc_no = $acc_no 
AND received_date BETWEEN '$startDate' AND {date('j-m-Y')}


where $startDate = "01-".date('m')."-".date('Y');
```

this but not getting the output what i want.

anyone can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell what answer you are getting and what answer you want

Comment: @RohitGupta i have two tables 1st named "members"  It has the detail of members and 2nd table named "deposit" it has the acc_no of member which is the primary key of member table.Now what i want is on selection of acc_no i want the details of that member and total of 'received_amount' field for that acc_no,so by doing SUM(received_amount) i am getting  that but i also want SUM(received_amount) but for current month only means 1st SUM(received_amount) is for total amount he has nd 2nd SUM(received_amount) which is for particular month means current month.hope u understand it.Thanks for help.